# Const in class method

Tags: c++, class, methods, constants

In this code I'm not really sure what does keyword "const" is doing.
My guess would be that it makes it not possible to change the private variables ​​of the class, but i'm not sure. 
Despite that I cannot understand the difference of "const" being ahead or behind the method. Or is it the same thing?

```
class Date
{
public:
    Date(unsigned int y, unsigned int m, unsigned int d);
    Date(string yearMonthDay); // yearMonthDay must be in format "yyyy/mm/dd"
    void setYear(unsigned int y);
    void setMonth(unsigned int m);
    void setDay(unsigned int d);
    void setDate(unsigned int y, unsigned int m, unsigned int d);
    unsigned int getYear() const;
    unsigned int getMonth() const;
    unsigned int getDay() const;
    string getDate() const; // returns the date in format "yyyy/mm/dd"
    void show() const; // shows the date on the screen in format "yyyy/mm/dd"
private:
    unsigned int year;
    unsigned int month;
    unsigned int day;
};
```

Comment: yes you are correct. I presume by "const before the method" you mean the part of the return type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you don't have a `Date` object at hands, but only a const reference to it, `const Date&`. You are only allowed to call const methods on that reference. These methods guarantee with their signature that they will not alter the `Date` object (and the compiler will also not allow it). An exception to this are `mutable` members.

A `const` keyword in front of the signature relates to the return argument. So for example, `const std::string& getName() const;` returns a const reference to a string. It is const itself, because it does not alter the object. These are the two meanings of `const` in front and end of the signature.